# MobileFirst 7.1 BusyIndicator showing weird characters

Tags: ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm developing an hybrid app on MobileFirst 7.1, with Ionic libraries.

In a .js file I globally define

```
var busyIndicator = new WL.BusyIndicator ("content", {text: "DUMMY TEXT"});
```

but when I call for it to show, i.e.

```
busyIndicator.show();
```

I always get the same message, ignoring the text I put in the text field:

[Image link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvp6k.png)

I'm testing this on Android devices (Huawei P7 Ascend, Samsung Galaxy J5, both with Android 5.1). On the Android Mobile Simulator the message displays just fine.

p.s. "content" matches my html id, I tried putting null instead of "content" but to no avail.

Comment: What happens when you test without Ionic?

Comment: Are you sure everything is UTF8? HTML page, js ?

Comment: @NazmulHasan I don't reckon using any special character around the whole project.

Comment: @IdanAdar Just tested: without Ionic it works fine, except my whole UI is gone of course :p

Comment: Then Ionic is somehow changing the text. It may be worth while to debug the app via chrome://inspect (if you're testing on a device) and put some breakpoints to see what is happening there.

Comment: @IdanAdar oh wow I got it, it seems that if you define the ionic ng-app property in the html tag, you need to use that same name in the BusyIndicator constructor, instead of "content", regardless of your html id.

Comment: Cool. :) Can you please write this as the answer for the question?

Comment: Done, thanks for pushing me the right way :D

Comment: @IdanAdar Ah sorry I partied way too soon: I had an indicator displayed in main.js right at the onLoad() event for testing, THAT indicator displays just fine with or without Ionic, regardless of the "content" value. Any other indicator displays the weird message, still regardless of the "content" value... I'm updating my question soon.

Comment: I would attempt debugging this by using chrome://inspect while running the app in device or emulator and put breakpoints to see what puts this weird text there.

Comment: Yeah thanks will do, will touch back when I'm done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A workaround**

define in some common .js file

```
function showMyIndicator() {
    busyIndicator.__options.text="Custom loading text";
    busyIndicator.show();
}
```

and call showMyIndicator() each time you would call busyIndicator.show().

busyIndicator.hide() can be called normally (although you might want to define some 'hideMyIndicator()' function for homogeneity).

**What is happening?**

It appears that, as soon as I load (jQuery $.load() ) some new content in order to change page, the text fileld of the busyIndicator object defaults to "[(')ههههههه Loading]", which is defined in every native project [inside messages.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wk8D.png).
That file is full of those weird signs, no idea about why.

**Update**

There's something corrupted in my project which causes those .json files to be generated with wrong characters, a freshly generated project didn't show the same issues so creating a new one and move the resources in there might do the trick.

Comment: errr, messages.json is provided by MFP. If you create a new app and you see this like in the image, please tell me the exact mfp version and build number. Looks like it is related to file encoding.

Comment: A new project in a new workspace gets a "healthy" messages.json file, without weird signs. I wonder how did I manage to corrupt it... at this rate I might just take the healthy file and paste it in each environment folder I guess?
I'm running MFP 7.1.0.00-20160217-1807 btw

Comment: I think the file is generated; I think you should create a new project and move over your code to it.

Comment: IIRC it's generated only once though, when its environment is added to the project. I'm checking this, then I'll report the whole thing in my answer.

Comment: ...aaaand you were right, just copy-pasting won't solve it ;)